# syncronization on other class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

As usual, we use syncronization like this:

```
Class A{
  public void method1{
      syncronized(this){
      } 
   } 
  public void method2{
      syncronized(this){
      } 
   } 
}
```

Someday, I found a code like this:

```
Class B{
      public void method3{
          syncronized(B.class){ //class level lock but lock itself
          } 
       }
    }
Class C{
      public void method4{
          syncronized(B.class){/class level lock but lock other class
          } 
       }
    }
```

As in the Class C indicates, it use B.class as its monitor. Assuming there are two threads t1 and t2 access Class C instance C1, and thread t3 access Class B instance B1, is there any effect to instace B1 or Class B  when t1 accesses C1?
is the B.class's role just a monitor like "this" in Class B ?

Comment: I would guess that's an artifact of copy/paste programming. Class C was probably created by copying class B, renaming it, and deleting the B-specific stuff.

Comment: @sisyphus  No. it's right code. As an example to discuss the problem.

Comment: We don't "usually" use synchronization like shown in the first code. It's misleading to manually synchronize on `this` instead of making the method `synchronized`. The second example on the other hand is bad and error prone programming.

Comment: That is to synchronize the task between each object of **Class C**.

Comment: @Kayaman  can you pls explain the the difference between Class B and Class C ?

Comment: Do you understand how synchronized works and what the parameter is used for? Class `C` just uses `B.class` to lock on, for no apparent good reason (at least based on the code shown). Even if there were a reason, that would be a very poor way to prevent `method3` and `method4` from running at the same time.

Comment: @Kayaman  so if thread t1 access method  method4(), meanwhile threads cannot access method3() anymore, is this right?

Comment: Yes. They're both trying to lock on `B.class`, and they can't hold the lock at the same time. Search a bit, there are plenty of questions/answers about how `synchronized` works (and doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you see this kind of thing in production code then you've probably got problems. However, it's relatively easy to understand.

The class instance of B is being used to synchronise both `B.method3()` and `C.method4()`. So, only 1 thread of control at a time can enter either of those methods regardless of the instance it's being called on. There's no other effect, unless you've got more things which synchronise on the class instance of B. It's quite a blunt weapon to be using for that reason - you can't quite be sure what else might be synchronising on B.class so the level of serialisation you're getting is not well-defined.

However, it's not a proper global, JVM-level synchronisation - different instances of B.class can exist in different classloaders so you need to be very careful about what you expect to happen if you do this kind of craziness. If you're trying to protect a global resource that should only ever be accessed by one thing at a time you might want to consider an alternative approach.

From a more general perspective, it's a bad idea to create this kind of dependency between B and C. It's not at all clear *why* C should have a method synchronised on B.class and so, over time, that reason could get lost. It's entirely possible that changes in `B` will mean that it's no longer necessary (or even appropriate) for `C` to synchronise on `B` in this fashion but you'll have no way of knowing.